# I am creating a database with content provider in android,but the database not working at all

Tags: java, android, sqlite

the is my main page of the note app coding:

```
public class Note_mainActivity extends Fragment implements NoteRecyclerAdapter.NoteOnClick,LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private RecyclerView mRecycler8;
private NoteRecyclerAdapter mAdapter8;
private List savedNote;
private MyDbHelper myDbHelper;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_note_main,container,false);
    savedNote = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecycler8 = (RecyclerView)rootView1.findViewById(R.id.show_note);
    WrappedLinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new WrappedLinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecycler8.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mAdapter8 = new NoteRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),this);
    mRecycler8.setItemAnimator(new SlideInDownAnimator());
    mRecycler8.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter8.setData(savedNote);
    myDbHelper = new MyDbHelper(getActivity());
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);
    return rootView1;
}

@Override
public void containerOnClick(int t) {

}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if(id==0){
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), NoteContract.NoteItemRow.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    }else{
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), NoteContract.NoteItemRow.CONTENT_URI_NEWS,null,null,null,null);
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if(loader.getId() ==0){
        if(data.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int title1 = data.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NOTE);
                int date1 = data.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.DATE);
                String title2 = data.getString(title1);
                String date2 = data.getString(date1);
                Notesetter setter1 = new Notesetter(title2,date2);
                savedNote.add(setter1);
                mAdapter8.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }while(data.moveToNext());

        }
    }else{
      /*  if(data.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int title2 = data.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_TITLE);
                int image_url = data.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_IMAGE);
                int source_url = data.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_URL);
                int date3 = data.getColumnIndex(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_DATE);
                String title3 = data.getString(title2);
                String image_url_3 = data.getString(image_url);
                String sources_url3 =data.getString(source_url);
                String date_saved3 = data.getString(date3);
                NewsNotesetter setter1 = new NewsNotesetter(title3,image_url_3,sources_url3,date_saved3);
                savedNote.add(setter1);
                mAdapter8.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }while(data.moveToNext());

        }*/
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

}

the is my content provider coding:

```
public class TheNewProvider extends ContentProvider {       
 private MyDbHelper myDbHelper;
 private static final String LOG_TAG = TheNewProvider.class.getSimpleName();
 private static final int SIMPLE_NOTE =100;
 private static final int SIMPLE_NOTE_ID=101;
 private static final int NEWS_NOTE =102;
 private static final int NEWS_NOTE_ID =103;
 private static final UriMatcher sUriMAtcher = new    UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static{
    sUriMAtcher.addURI(NoteContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, NoteContract.path_note,SIMPLE_NOTE);
    sUriMAtcher.addURI(NoteContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, NoteContract.path_note+"/#",SIMPLE_NOTE_ID);
    sUriMAtcher.addURI(NoteContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, NoteContract.path_news,NEWS_NOTE);
    sUriMAtcher.addURI(NoteContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, NoteContract.path_news+"/#",NEWS_NOTE_ID);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    myDbHelper = new MyDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    int match = sUriMAtcher.match(uri);
    switch (match){
        case SIMPLE_NOTE:
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        case SIMPLE_NOTE_ID:
            selection = NoteContract.NoteItemRow._ID+"=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);

            break;
        case NEWS_NOTE:
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        case NEWS_NOTE_ID:
            selection = NoteContract.NoteItemRow._ID+"=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported" +uri);

    }
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), NoteContract.NoteItemRow.CONTENT_URI);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), NoteContract.NoteItemRow.CONTENT_URI_NEWS);
    return cursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values) {
    final int match = sUriMAtcher.match(uri);
    switch (match){
        case SIMPLE_NOTE:
            return save(uri,values);

        case NEWS_NOTE:
            return saveNews(uri,values);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported" +uri);
    }
}

@Override
public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
    final int match = sUriMAtcher.match(uri);
    switch (match){
        case SIMPLE_NOTE:
            return UpdateNote(uri,values,selection,selectionArgs);
        case SIMPLE_NOTE_ID:
            selection = NoteContract.NoteItemRow._ID+"=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            return UpdateNote(uri,values,selection,selectionArgs);
        case NEWS_NOTE:
            return UpdateNews(uri,values,selection,selectionArgs);
        case NEWS_NOTE_ID:
            selection = NoteContract.NoteItemRow._ID+"=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            return UpdateNews(uri,values,selection,selectionArgs);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insertion is not supported" +uri);
    }
}

private Uri save(Uri url,ContentValues values){
    String name  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TITLE);
    if(name == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no title");
    }
    String notes  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NOTE);
    if(notes == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no note");
    }
    String date  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.DATE);
    if(date == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no date");
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long id = db.insert(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    if(id==-1){
        Log.v("the note","saved");
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url,null);
    return ContentUris.withAppendedId(url,id);
}
private Uri saveNews(Uri url,ContentValues values){
    String name  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_TITLE);
    if(name == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no title");
    }
    String notes  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_URL);
    if(notes == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no note");
    }
    String date  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_DATE);
    if(date == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no date");
    }
    String image_url  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_IMAGE);
    if(image_url == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no image");
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long id = db.insert(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    if(id==-1){
        Log.v("the note","saved");
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url,null);
    return ContentUris.withAppendedId(url,id);
}
private int UpdateNote(Uri url,ContentValues values,String selection,String[]selectionArgs){
    String name  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TITLE);
    if(name == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no title");
    }
    String notes  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NOTE);
    if(notes == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no note");
    }
    String date  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.DATE);
    if(date == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no date");
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowUpdated = db.update(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
    if(rowUpdated!=0){
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url,null);
    }

    return rowUpdated;
}
private int UpdateNews(Uri url,ContentValues values,String selection,String[]selectionArgs){
    String name  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_TITLE);
    if(name == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no title");
    }
    String notes  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_URL);
    if(notes == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no note");
    }
    String date  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_DATE);
    if(date == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no date");
    }
    String image_url  = values.getAsString(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NEWS_IMAGE);
    if(image_url == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no image");
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowUpdated = db.update(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
    if(rowUpdated!=0){
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url,null);
    }

    return rowUpdated;
}
```

}

this is my databasehelper class:

```
public class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABSE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="simpleTable.db";

private static final String createDatabase = "CREATE TABLE "
        + NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME
        +"("+NoteItemRow._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +NoteItemRow.TITLE+" TEXT, "
        +NoteItemRow.NOTE+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
        +NoteItemRow.DATE+" TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static final String createDatabase2 = "CREATE TABLE "
        + NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME2
        +"("+NoteItemRow._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +NoteItemRow.NEWS_TITLE+" TEXT, "
        +NoteItemRow.NEWS_URL+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
        +NoteItemRow.NEWS_DATE+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
        +NoteItemRow.NEWS_IMAGE+" TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static final String UPGRADE_DB = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME;

private static final String UPGRADE_DB2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ NoteItemRow.TABLE_NAME2;

public MyDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABSE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(createDatabase);
    db.execSQL(createDatabase2);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL(UPGRADE_DB);
    db.execSQL(UPGRADE_DB2);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}
this is my editnote class:

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText mTitle,mNote;
String title1;
String note_detail;
private MyDbHelper mDbHelper;
private Uri cureenturi;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note_editor);
    mTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_note);
    mNote = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.take_note);


}
private void savenote(){
     title1 = mTitle.getText().toString().trim();
     note_detail = mNote.getText().toString().trim();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    Date date = new Date();
    String date_cur = sdf.format(date);
    mDbHelper = new MyDbHelper(this);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.TITLE,title1);
    values.put(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.NOTE,note_detail);
    values.put(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.DATE,date_cur);
    cureenturi = getContentResolver().insert(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.CONTENT_URI,values);
    if(cureenturi == null){
        return;
    }else {
        int updateRow = getContentResolver().update(cureenturi,values,null,null);
        if(updateRow==0){

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this,"note updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    Uri newUriContent =  getContentResolver().insert(NoteContract.NoteItemRow.CONTENT_URI,values);
    if(newUriContent==null){
        Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this,"can't created the note",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this,"note inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(title1)&&TextUtils.isEmpty(note_detail)){
        finish();
    }else{
        savenote();
    }
```

}

when i launch the app the error log show this error:

```
Process: com.example.user.inforting, PID: 5490
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.example.user.inforting.Note_mainActivity.onLoadFinished(Note_mainActivity.java:72)
                                                                          at com.example.user.inforting.Note_mainActivity.onLoadFinished(Note_mainActivity.java:30)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:476)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:444)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:126)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:105)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:37)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:252)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:80)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:485)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:502)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

someone can help to correct me. your help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see program error logs it says:

'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' **on a null object reference**

And also **MoveToFirst** method,Move the cursor to the first row.

So as my opinion,You have not initiated your SQLiteDataBase Well or You lose your reference Object of DataBase through your program.

hope it would be helpful.

Comment: thank you for your reply and this helps me a lot.   but now another problem occur is the fragment cannot inflate my recyclerview with my recyclerviewAdapter and the error just show nothing, and the screen just shows the blank screen, can you help to check recyclerview coding, correct me also, thank a lot.